# Adding Analytics Event Tracking to A Tag or Div Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, analytics

I have a button on my website that I would like to track in Google Analytics.

```
<div id="contact_btn"  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
<a href="{{ ('mailto:' + job.poster.email) if request.authenticated_userid else request.route_path('login_signup') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button" id="gaContactBtn">Contact Poster</a>
</div>
```

From another Stack question I ran into this code;

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'contact_btn');"
```

So I created a custom Goal in Google Analytics with the following settings.

Category: button

Action: click

Label: gaContactBtn

Value:

My question is.. Can I put the code above on the A tag, or the DIV tag? Will it still work? After doing some searching I found a jQuery event tracking generator which provided me with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a#gaContactBtn").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).click(function(event) { // when someone clicks these links
        event.preventDefault(); // don't open the link yet
        _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Link", "Click", text, , false]); // create a custom event
        setTimeout(function() { // now wait 300 milliseconds...
            window.open(href,(!target?"_self":target)); // ...and open the link as usual
        },300);
    });
  });
});
```

Is this a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you call called ga() can be applied from any place of the dom or the javascript after the google analytics loaded. So yes you can use it from anywhere and anytime you want...

Comment: 1. So even if I have the ga() on the DIV, will it still be executed when the A button is clicked?
2. Does the ID in the ga() need to match the ID of the tag it is embedded in?

Comment: That is not refferring to dom element id, that is an event parameret or something. And no, you need to add the code on the dom element you want to fire the event... you can attach it to any event, onclick onkeypress ....